# Mapping 2d vector to RGB colors for debugging?

Tags: colors

So I'm working on a simulation in which I calculate a 2d velocity vector field. Now I would like to visualize the direction of the volicity as colors.

Currently I'm converting the velocity to a color as follows:

```
var vel = _velocity[x][y]; // _velocity is the velocity field
var velNor = velVec.normalized;
var color = new Color(.5f + .5f * velNor.x,  .5f + .5f * velNor.z, 0.5f);
```

And this works fine. However I'm not really using the third (blue) color channel. Using the blue channel could give a clearer image of the direction.

However, I'm not sure how to convert it properly. I would like the directions to map to colors like on a color wheel:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured something out using hue. I've implemented it in a shader as follows:

```
float3 Hue(float H)
{
    float R = abs(H * 6 - 3) - 1;
    float G = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 2);
    float B = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 4);
    return saturate(float3(R, G, B));
}

float4 vel = tex2D(_VelocityXYTex, IN.uv_VelocityXYTex);
float velDir = (1 + atan2(vel.g, vel.r) / 3.141592) / 2; //map -pi,pi to 0,1
float4 velColor = float4(Hue(velDir), 1);
```